# Xcode 3 recognizes my OS X application as an iOS app

Tags: xcode

I always use *a future version of Xcode* to write my software, occasionally checking back in Xcode 3 to see whether the application still compiles there. It usually does. However, today I found out that Xcode 3 detects the application as iOS and not OS X.

I checked the Base SDK, and it's fine. I checked the architectures, deployment target, etc.

To illustrate the issue, here's a screenshot

[image]

Again, my application is **not** an iOS application, but an OS X application.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Yes, the Target is called "Mac".

Comment: I assume you use version control. Have you tried looking at the changes introduced to project.pbxproj since you last verified that Xcode 3 worked fine?

Comment: That has been quite some time, but yes, I have. Xcode does, however, seem to re-order the properties a lot so it's hard to compare. I did look through them but didn't find anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it was a silly caching issue...

Apparently Xcode 3 builds a user profile within the project directory - of course, these files are hidden and I didn't even think about looking at them.

When the only thing I couldn't find in the project file was a solution, I noticed these two files sitting in the project directory. I closed the project, deleted the files, and opened the project again. Xcode 3 marked the project as an OS X application again!

*Summary of the above:* **Delete the user profile and it will work again.**